# Turning a Node.js script into a Firebase Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a node.js script that works perfectly when running from command line, but when I try to use it as a function fails.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.dailyUpdate = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 5 * * *')
.onRun((context) => {
db.collection("meters")
  .get()
  .then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
      let mtrList = meterlist.push([
        doc.id,
      ]);
      return true;
    });

    meterlist
      .forEach(function (obj) {
        var meterid = obj[0];
        var meterdata;
        var history = [];

        axios
          .get(url)
          .then((response) => {
            metername = meterid.toString();
            meterdata = response.data.meterdata;
            if (meterdata) {
              meterdata.forEach(function (obj) {
                let datadate = obj.stamp.substring(0, 10);
                let datatime = obj.stamp.substring(11, 13);
                let data = obj.data;
                history.push({
                  metername: metername,
                  datadate: datadate,
                  datatime: datatime,
                  data: data,
                });
              });

let todayUpdate = runCalculations(history);

               updateDB(todayUpdate);
            }
            return Promise.resolve("done!");
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
        return true;
      })
    return true;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

  response.send("Updated!!");
});
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but when I, for example put the `require`s in the code section,

```
const axios = require("axios");
const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");
var moment = require("moment");
var _ = require("lodash");
var Promise = require("promise");
```

doesn't run because it doesn't know where axios is. When I place them before the `exports...` below the `const functions = require('firebase-functions');` I get different errors, including: ""Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'axios'" // Provided module can't be loaded. // Could not load the function, shutting down. // Function cannot be initialized. "

The script itself runs a `querySnapshot` from a Firestore db, parses the results, calls an api through `axios`, runs a bunch of calculations, and then updates the db with the updated results. And I want this to run at 5:05AM every day.

I did not make any changes to the actual code of the script besides including the above `exports` code.

What am I missing?

Comment: What are the actual error messages you are seeing?  You say you get errors but don't describe what the errors are.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the actual code and error messages.  We need to see the [complete minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Keep in mind also that you will almost certainly need to make changes to the code in order to ensure that the function [terminates correctly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  Don't just blindly copy everything in place - Cloud Functions has special requirements.

Comment: "Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'axios'" // Provided module can't be loaded. // Could not load the function, shutting down. // Function cannot be initialized.

Comment: Did you use npm to install the modules you're using for this project?

Comment: @DougStevenson I think that was my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy a Cloud Function, the node_modules directory *needs to be populated*, or you need to use Webpack (or some such) to include the dependencies.  Firebase Deploy seems to *essentially* Zip the entire directory, upload and then *run* it in the cloud to deploy the *specific* function as called out in the entry point.  All the dependencies need to be present in one form or another.

I happen to use a slightly unconventional approach to this, but the net-net is that Cloud Functions **ARE NOT** just another host to deploy to - they have *quite* specific formats and functions you need to follow.  Read the documentation.  Read it again.  Walk through the samples.  Then remember the samples are the *simplest* approach, but not the only approach.

Comment: The Firebase CLI will not actually deploy node_modules at all.  In fact, it deploys everything but that.  Cloud Functions will reconstitute that before it creates a docker image for that function.  It's essential that package.json and package-lock.json are up to date.

Comment: You would think that - but if the node_modules folder is not present, it will not deploy.  How do I know?  I just tried it.  It might not upload the node_modules folder, but I immediately got a "module not found" when I ran ```firebase deploy``` after deleting the node_modules folder.  *might* be because I use a somewhat unusual folder/deploy structure.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't have to be present on the local machine at the time of deployment. I'm just saying it doesn't get deployed.  So when you said " Firebase Deploy seems to essentially Zip the entire directory", that's not really true.